# when I run my app on localhost am able to display images on html but when I deploy to a cloud platform am getting 404 for the images

Tags: java

This is my rest end point saving the image to a local file system but with reference id to MYSQL db.

Now how can I make some modifications to my folder where the images are being stored or in my application properties file to make sure I display them on html when I deploy my app to any cloud platform.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addBook(Model model) {
        Book book = new Book();
        model.addAttribute("book", book);
        return "addBook";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addBookPost(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book, HttpServletRequest request) {
            bookService.save(book);
    
            MultipartFile bookImage = book.getBookImage();
    
            try {
                byte[] bytes = bookImage.getBytes();
                String name = book.getId() + ".png";
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(new File("src/main/resources/static/image/book/" + name)));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            return "redirect:bookList";
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You would need to load the files as a resource, not a file--they're not a file when they're in a jar. That said, if this is anything other than an example/test/school project, static resources like images should almost never be bundled as part of the code's source, rather as external resources.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have this hardcoded path to locate the image: `src/main/resources/static/image/book/`. In order to load that image on a cloud server, you must recreate the exact same path on the server.

Alternatively you can upload the file to a different path and specify that path instead. Better yet, allow the path to be more dynamic so you can configure it based on which environment the app runs in.